# What do these Foreign Investment icons mean?

Tags: the-third-world-war

I just started playing [The Third World War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_World_War_(video_game)) for Sega CD, and I'm interested in doing some overseas investing, but I'm not sure what the icons for the different categories mean.

When I go to Economic Policies > Foreign Invest > Region, I am presented with this screen:

[image: Foreign Investment Icons]

I have to select a country, and then one of those icons for the country ($$, house, truck, etc.).

What do the icons mean?

Comment: Looks like residential, industrial, and commercial, much like sim city

Comment: @Ender Yes, that seems right. After some time in the game I'm starting to get the hang of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't do a good job of asking the question. I should have also asked, what do the bars represent? Whats the benefit?

Each time you invest in an area, say housing, it's bar will be reduced (towards the left). Once it's been reduced all the way, the foreign investor will control that market and their flag will appear next to the icon. If the same country controls all four areas in a country then the **ECON** count goes up by one, and with it I assume other things like monthly and yearly revenue.